# Attach a function to the Window without onload - React & Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

### The Problem

I have an external script using it in a React Next.js Project.  https://app.lemonsqueezy.com/js/checkout.js

However, the script not functioning properly when opening the page using `next/link` component from other pages. I think the reason is that the above script attaches to the window based on the `onLoad` function and in Next.js, `onLoad` does not trigger when navigating from another page.

So I need a way to manually attach the function to the window using `next/script` component.

The corresponding checkout JS has something like this in their script.

```js
function i() {
      window.LemonSqueezyCheckout ||
        (window.LemonSqueezyCheckout = new t());
    }
    window.addEventListener
      ? window.addEventListener("load", i)
      : window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload", i);
```

So I have tried adding to window using the `next/script` component but its not working.

```js
<Script src="https://app.lemonsqueezy.com/js/checkout.js"
        onLoad={() => {
         // Attach to window when loaded
         window.LemonSqueezyCheckout = new t()
        }} />
```

#### Live Demo

https://nextjs-djqrvw.stackblitz.io

#### Minimal reproduction

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-djqrvw?file=pages%2Fnext.js

### Expected Result

The script function should attach to Window even when clicking from Other pages using `next/link`. Once its attached. Clicking on Popup will open an actual popup instead of navigating to another page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `onLoad={ }` is the notation for an object. It is expected to be `onLoad={ "key1" : value1, "key2" : value2 }`. Instead, you wrote a function inside. `onLoad={() => {window.LemonSqueezyCheckout = new t()}}`. This is invalid syntax, and your console must be telling you `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('`. Remove the outer `{ }`. Also it's `onload` not `onLoad`. `onload= () =>{ ... };`

Comment: @JeremyThille I think wrapping in  `{ }` is correct formating because React expects to wrap these functions like that. So, your code actually gives me syntax error. Also see Official docs wrote `onLoad` here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#executing-code-after-loading-onload

Are you able to think any other reason?

Comment: Ah, sorry, ignore me then. I know next to nothing about React

Answer (score 1):

The team of custom script I was using pushed a new fix which includes the refresh of that function. So now I was able to fix it using the below code.

```js
import Script from "next/script";

export default function Page() {
  function lemonLoaded() {
    window.createLemonSqueezyCheckout();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src="https://app.lemonsqueezy.com/js/checkout.js"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
        onLoad={() => {
          lemonLoaded();
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```